# Refer to field name instead of index position in ArcPy cursor

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, arcgis-10.7

With ArcPy cursors, we can refer to fields by using the field index position:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class, ["ASSET_ID","ROAD_ID","CLASS","OWNER","SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[2]
```

In some cases, if we have lots of fields, it would be less error-prone to refer to field names instead of the index numbers.

Fake example:

```
print row["CLASS"]
```

---

With ArcPy cursors, is there a way to refer to a field name instead of the index position?

Comment: The overhead associated with that sort of processing is what caused the demise of the original cursor model, but it's trivial to create a dictionary of field names that returns position `print row[lookup['CLASS']]`

Comment: BTW SHAPE is wrong name for geometry field, try Shape@ instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [tuple unpacking](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20tuple%20unpacking)

```
flds = ["ASSET_ID","ROAD_ID","CLASS","OWNER","SHAPE@"]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class, flds) as rows:
    for asset_id, road_id, class_, owner, shape in rows:  # class is a reserved word in python so I use class_
        print(class_)
```

Or @Vince's suggestion of a dict of fieldname: index

```
flds = ["ASSET_ID","ROAD_ID","CLASS","OWNER","SHAPE@"]
lookup = {v:i for i, v in enumerate(flds)}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class, flds) as rows:
    for row in rows:  
        print(row[lookup['CLASS']])
```

Or [namedtuple or dict generators](https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/getting-arcpy-da-rows-back-as-dictionaries/):

```
# namedtuple generator
from collections import namedtuple

def rows_as_namedtuples(cursor):
    cursor_row = namedtuple('Row', cursor.fields)
    for row in cursor:
        yield cursor_row(*row)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class, flds) as rows:
    for row in rows_as_namedtuples(rows):  
        print(row.CLASS)

# dict generator
def rows_as_dicts(cursor):
    fields = cursor.fields
    for row in cursor:
        yield dict(zip(fields, row))

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class, flds) as rows:
    for row in rows_as_dicts(rows):
        print(row['CLASS'])
```

Note on speed of execution - tuple unpacking is theoretically faster because there's no expensive lookup, but I ran some [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) benchmarks on all of these methods (including @polygeo's index method) and the execution times were pretty much exactly the same, all the overhead is in the cursor, any differences caused by how you access the row values is relatively negligible.

Comment: A note on the "dict generator" version-- `cursor.fields` is actually a getter, so accessing that property has more of a performance overhead than you'd expect.  If you create a `fields` var outside of the loop then that approach will be a bit faster

Comment: Change made, haven't run any `timeit` benchmarks again, but don't think it'll make any noticeable difference (relative to the time it takes for the cursor setup and data access), but hey, every little bit helps!

Comment: I only knew this because it _has_ made a noticeable difference in my experience, although I'm sure it depends on the dataset

Comment: Yeah, I was only testing on a small dataset (~200 rows) and all (orig) methods were very close. Perhaps makes more of a difference with larger datasets

Comment: I agree with @user2856.  I see tuple unpacking as the most idiomatic way of handling cursor rows, and I use it almost exclusively, especially with Python 3's support for extended tuple unpacking.  If there are so many columns in the cursor that tuple unpacking is unwieldy, then it usually indicates a larger issue with workflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you set a variable like:

```
flds = ["ASSET_ID", "ROAD_ID", "CLASS", "OWNER","SHAPE"]
```

you could then do this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class, flds) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[flds.index("CLASS")])
```

but I think it is far better to use the index number direct.